# Setup template for image based on bool value within a Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, datatemplate

Here is my Customer class and its collection that I want to display in a page.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Validated { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer() { Validated = false, Name = "Dude", Details = "some details" },
                new Customer() { Validated = false, Name = "Person", Details = "some details" },
                new Customer() { Validated = true, Name = "Friend", Details = "some details" },
                new Customer() { Validated = false, Name = "Buddy", Details = "some details" },
            };
```

I am trying to create a data template for this data in a list control. For the Image, I want to display different image based on Validated field. Below is what I have done so far but I don't know how to set up template for image.

```
<Page x:Class="MyTestPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="500"
    Title="MyTestPage" >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lst1"  Grid.Row="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="20" Content="Name" />
                                    <Label FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="18" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" Content="Details" />
                                    <Label FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Details}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"  Height="100" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Button Content="Close" Margin="5" Width="60" Click="Close_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any ideas about how can I setup image template within this data template?

Comment: Read the [Data Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion) section of the Data Binding Overview article on MSDN.

Comment: I have create the template above after reading couple of articles on this, however, when googling about it there seem like many ways of accomplishing this (with and without converters). I am not sure what's the best approach for this scenario.

Comment: @johnsmith use disabled `ToggleButton` or `CheckBox` with custom `Template` that will show one image or the other depending on `IsChecked` being true or false

Comment: @dkozi: Can you show some example what exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom converter implementing the [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, which returns the wanted [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based on the binding value, you probably only need to create the logic for the `Convert` method so you can leave the `ConvertBack` method as is

add your converter to the resources like so

`<Page.Resources>
    <myConverters:MyValueConverter x:Key="MyCustomValueConverter"/>
    <!-- dont forget to add the xmlns to the page -->
</page.Resources>`

and add it to the binding of your image

your xaml image will look something like this:

`<Image Source="{Binding Validated, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomValueConverter}" Height="100" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>`